# fancyBox 2: preloading gallery images in both directions

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is there an easy modification of the source code so that the option of preloading the gallery images runs in both directions?

Now only the next images are preloaded but it could be senseful in some cases if also the previous images are preloaded, so that e.g. if one chooses the number of 3 preloaded images the next 3 and the previous 3 images are preloaded. Then the user can easily go forward or back within the gallery.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering this myself and it seems you can edit the _preloadImages function slightly to accomplish this. Duplicate the contents inside the for-loop and only change the plus to a minus.

So,

```
        for (i = 1; i <= cnt; i += 1) {
            item = group[ (current.index + i ) % len ];

            if (item.type === 'image' && item.href) {
                new Image().src = item.href;
            }
        }
```

becomes:

```
        for (i = 1; i <= cnt; i += 1) {
            item = group[ (current.index + i ) % len ];

            if (item.type === 'image' && item.href) {
                new Image().src = item.href;
            }

            item = group[ (current.index - i ) % len ];

            if (item.type === 'image' && item.href) {
                new Image().src = item.href;
            }
        }
```

This seems to work after quick testing so for example if you change the preload to 1 it now preloads only the ones on either side of the current item.

(This was on Fancybox v2.1.5)

edit: After some more testing, it seems you also need to add a check to prevent negative group items, like this:

```
            if (current.index - i >= 0) {
                item = group[ (current.index - i ) % len ];

                if (item.type === 'image' && item.href) {
                    new Image().src = item.href;
                }
            }
```